# Recycle bitmaps on a listview causes issues

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, row, recycle

I got a list view where im displaying images, these images are downloaded and cache properly. As I scroll down the list and load new items I want to recycle the least recently used ones to save on memory. I have successfully implemented the LRU Map and im  calling recycle on bitmaps which are not visible on the screen. Here is part of the code:

imageView is a ViewGroup

```
public void recycleImage(int res) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        if (res > 0)
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(res);
    }

    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        bitmap.recycle();

        Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap recycled");
    }
}
```

Those values are saved on the getView method of the adapter. The problem is that as I recycle images I can see how the ones visible on the screen also get lost (note im only recycling the ones I know are out of the screen).

Does anyone have an idea of why im losing the images currently displayed when I recycled the bitmaps of others on the listview?

This is where I access the stored bitmap or download it.

```
   if (mImageMap.containsKey(url)) { 
       ImageCacheModel cache = mImageMap.get(url); 
       return cache.getBitmap(); 
   } else if (cacheManager.isUrlCached(url)) { 
       mImageMap.put(url, new ImageCacheModel(imageView, cacheManager.getCachedBitmapOrNull(url, 2)));

        ImageCacheModel cache = mImageMap.get(url);
        return cache.getBitmap();
    } else {
        cacheManager.addUrlToQueue(url, this, true);
    }
```

Comment: I'm missing where you get bitmap from?

Comment: lazy loading from a web service. Saved to the internal storage.

Comment: Where are you initializing the variable and put content in bitmap? In short, show more code please

Comment: I edited the answer. It got wrongly formatted but its bassically, if it doesnt find it in the temporary cache then it try the permanent cache (internal disk) and if that also fails it downloads it from the web.

Comment: still not what I'm asking after. In your methode recycleImage() you use bitmap <--- where is the reference to bitmap, is bitmap a field or is a parameter you left out?

Comment: bitmap is part of a class initialised this way:

 public ImageCacheModel(ViewGroup imageView, Bitmap bitmap) {
  this.imageView = imageView;
  this.bitmap = bitmap;
  
 }

A new instance is created for every row of the list. Then when needed this bitmap is recycled and the imageView clear its bitmap reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember that your `ImageView` inside your `convertView` (list element) is being reused all the time. In short you don't create a new `convertView` every time a new view shows up from the `ListView` you actually just reuse the last element that scrolled out.

So in your case lets say you have a list where 3 items are visible at any time. When you clear item 1 you also clear item 4 and item 7 etc. etc.

I can't point to the exact point where this issue bites you but based on what you describe I'm almost certain this is the issue.

Comment: Yes thats true. I managed to get around the issue and Im able to recycle the bitmaps without touching its ImageView.

Do you know any way to keep get a callback on recycled views?

Comment: @aldroid your getView() is where they are being recycled. I'd recommend you this clip from google I/O 2010: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 it touches a lot of important things on listview and performance etc. Also I hope you use ViewHolder pattern. If not you HAVE to give it a watch :)